# How to do an "in" expression with a previously defined/let externaldata

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Suppose I have a query like so:

```
SomeTable
| where Col1 !in (externaldata (something:string) [  @"https://...."])
```

However, if I have previously defined externaldata table in a let I cannot do this - syntax error:

```
let exttable=externaldata (something:string) [  @"https://...."]) 
Sometable
| where Col1 !in exttable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments for the "in" operator must be enclosed in parenthesis for example:

```
let exttable=externaldata (something:string) [  @"https://...."]) 
Sometable
| where Col1 !in (exttable)
```

If you inline this expression then you will need double parenthesis  such as:

```
Sometable
| where Col1 !in ((externaldata (something:string) [  @"https://...."]) ))
```